# How Can I Change This $.extend Variable?

Tags: jquery

I need to change a variable's value and can't find a way to do so. Here's an abbreviated excerpt of a very large script in which the variable is contained.

```
(function ($, window, document) {
"use strict";
    func1() {}
    func2() {}
    ...
        $.extend({
            something: function (options) {

            var self = this,
                var1,
                var2,
                **variable_I_want_to_modify**,
                var4,
                ...
        }, options),
    func8() {}
    func9() {**variable_I_want_to_modify** used in this function}
    ...
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

The instantiation is done like this:

```
var myInstance = new $.something(..options..)
```

I've tried too many approaches to list here.
Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: "variable_I_want_to_modify used in this function" doesnt really tell us much. Show  us how that variable is defined/used in `func9`?.

Comment: Also, are you able to edit this code, or is it a script included from elsewhere etc..?

Comment: In func9() the variable is checked to see if it is set to true. It's a 3rd party's code, so I can't change the script; it resides on their server. The code in func9() is essentially like this:

            self.doSomething = function () {
                if (**variable_I_want_to_modify**) {
                        signalR_obj.server.terminateSession();
            };

Comment: `if (variable_I_want_to_modify)` still doesnt tell us how `func9` is actually getting the variable. As it stands you show the variable being **defined** inside one function, then show that same variable being **used** in another function at the same nested level. The body of these two functions are not in the same scope, that would not work. The functions must be setting and accessing that variable in a different way than you are showing, otherwise, *variable_I_want_to_modify* would always be *undefined* inside func9

Comment: The variable is set inside another function that looks like this:
            self.doSomethingElse = function () {
                _variable_I_want_to_modify_ = true;
                _other operations which I do NOT want performed, so I don't want to call this function just for the sake of setting the variable to true_
            };
In func9, the only reason I want to set the variable to _true_ is so it will call the signalR disconnect. It's a chat app, and when the user chooses to exit the chat it needs to disconnect; otherwise, the responding agent will think the chat is still active.

Comment: What library are you using exactly? What you describe sounds like a common enough task with a chat app that they may have a separate method to do what you need already.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't name the library because it's proprietary. I can tell you that it makes use of jQuery, jQuery-UI, and signalR. Nonetheless, you're very astute: it does have a method specific to ending the connection:  
    self.function = disconnect() { $.connection.disconnect(); };  
However, when called, it throws the error: "TypeError: $.connection.disconnect is not a function"

Comment: I think perhaps the answer lies in this article. [link](https://johnresig.com/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)  I'm experimenting with it now.

Comment: Ive added an *answer* since a comment would be too short to explain, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

We cant answer your sepecific question without seeing more of the code which you've said you cant show. You mention in your comment [Simple JavaScript Inheritance by John Resig](https://johnresig.com/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) and that may help you understand the problem.

To point you in the right direction, consider this part of the code:

```
(function ($, window, document) { 

 //..... 

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

This is called a closure. The issue is that this closure creates its own *scope* inside it. That is to say that methods defined inside it like `func9`, only exist there and can only be called from there. They are not exposed to the reset of the scripts around it (outside the brackets). This is intentionally done to avoid naming conflicts and such with other scripts that might also define a `func9`.

Note that at the bottom/end of the closure we see `jQuery, window, document`, there are variables from the environment around the closure that we want to pass into it.

At the top/start of the closure `($, window, document)` this is those variables being passed in, they've just chosen to name the `jQuery` variable `$` when passing it in to make it easier to use.

Now consider below code from inside that closure:

```
    $.extend({
        something: function (options) {

        //...
    }, options),
```

By calling `$.extend(` the code is taking the jQuery object that was passed in and *extending* it to add the method `something`. This can be looked at as *exporting* the method to the outside world. Because the jQuery object already existed outside the scope of the main closure (remember we passed it in), and we have added a method to it, we can now call that method from outside the closure like you show:

```
var myInstance = new $.something(..options..)
```

What does this mean for your question?

Well, that's hard to say without seeing the actual code or it's documentation which you cant show.

Basically, it means that you cannot modify  **variable_I_want_to_modify** which exists in side the scope of the closure unless the creators expose a method from inside that closure that somehow lets you do so. It's very likely that the creators did in fact give you a way to do what you need. Maybe you can find that method now, armed with a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for the informative feedback. I tried to up-vote it, but I don't have enough credits to do so. I scoured the chat library and could not find anything that exposes the variable in question. However, I found that I could get a reference to the library's signalR hub, so I used that to accomplish my goal: terminate the connection. And thus ends this saga... :-)